# Numerical errors in Plots

Tags: plotting, numerics

I am having quite a bit of trouble with some plots I am trying to create. Basically, as I decrease a positive parameter 'mu' to below 10^-8, my ListPlot3D plots are becoming fuzzy and eventually just a pile of fuzz. I present the code below.

If you run the code you will create a plot that has "fuzziness", for a bigger 'mu' this disappears and for a smaller 'mu', it gets worse.

Am I having a precision problem? I have tried SetPrecision to improve it and also tried using Plot3D rather than ListPlot3D but I just cannot create nice "normal" plots.

I know this is a bit of code, so I'll be extremely happy for any help.

```
(*Create coord triplets from 3 lists.*)
pairUp3C[xValues_, yValues_, 
   zValues_] := ({xValues[[#]], yValues[[#]], zValues[[#]]}) & /@ 
   Range[Length[xValues]];


    \[Mu] = 5*10^(-8);
beta = i*\[Mu]/Sqrt[2];
theta = Pi/2;
x = beta;
y = Conjugate[beta];

gridint = 0.1;
grid = Flatten[Table[x + I*y, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}]];

(*OPERATORS*)
A[x_, y_, F_] := E^(+x #1 - y #2) F[#1 - y/2, #2 - x/2] - F[#1, #2];
AD[x_, y_, F_] := E^(-x #1 + y #2) F[#1 - y/2, #2 - x/2] - F[#1, #2];

F0 := E^(-2*#1 #2) &;
W3 = SetPrecision[AD[x, y, Evaluate[SetPrecision[A[x, y, F0], 80]] &],
     80]; // Chop

(*EVALUATION AND PLOTTING*)
d = Flatten[
  Table[SetPrecision[
    W3 /. {#1 -> (x0 + I*y0)/\[Sqrt]2, #2 -> (x0 - I*y0)/\[Sqrt]2}, 
    80], {x0, -4, 4, 0.1}, {y0, -4, 4, 0.1}]]

d1 = SetPrecision[Total[d]*gridint^2, 80];

qvals = Flatten[Table[Re[grid[[o]]], {o, 1, 6561}]];
pvals = Flatten[Table[Im[grid[[o]]], {o, 1, 6561}]];
dvals = Flatten[Table[Re[d[[o]]], {o, 1, 6561}]];

f = pairUp3C[qvals, pvals, dvals/d1]

ListPlot3D[SetPrecision[f, 80], PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Comment: We are missing the definition of `pairUp3C`. Also, a hint: 0.1 has less precision than 1/10. `SetPrecision` does not make up for that.

Comment: thankyou - i will try to work with your hint and add the pairup3C code.

Comment: I solved my problem! I ended up using an analytical version of the plot and Plot3D then increased the working precision to 100. Worked a charm. :)

Comment: Great! Please consider writing an answer to your question, so that others can benefit from it in the future.